# Adding conditional to stop flatmap's 2nd HTTP call

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having issues figuring out where to put a conditional in the PUT request. In order to update email, the user has to  pass an id and email test which you can see in getUserInfo(). I was trying to pass a boolean of the result to the second function to bail and not attempt PUT request without reloading page if the result is false since I don't want to update information which failed validation. Wherever I put a conditional statement after the

`return this.getUserInfo(this.userId, oldEmail, newEmail, result)`

I get an error. I appreciate the help!

```
   getUserInfo(id: string, oldEmail: string, newEmail: string, result: boolean) {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/user/${id}`)
      .pipe(
        tap(value => 'output: ' + "TEST" + value),
        tap(res => {
          if (this.userId === res["posts"]._id && oldEmail === res["posts"].email) {
            console.log("You passed the id and email test");
            result = true;
          }
          else {
            result = false;
            console.log("You failed the test!");
            return;
          }
        })
      );
  }

  updateUserEmail(id: string, oldEmail: string, newEmail: string, result: boolean) {


    const updateEmail: UserEmailChange = {
      id: id, oldEmail: oldEmail, newEmail: newEmail
    };

    return this.getUserInfo(this.userId, oldEmail, newEmail, result)

      .pipe(

        flatMap(userInfo =>

          this.http.put(`http://localhost:3000/api/user/`, id))
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can throw an error:

```
return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/user/${id}`)
    .pipe(
    mergeMap(res => {
          if (this.userId === res["posts"]._id && oldEmail === res["posts"].email) {
          console.log("You passed the id and email test");
          throwError({error: 'not found'});
        }
        else {
          return of(true);
        }
    })
    );
}
```

And when you call it:

```
return this.getUserInfo(this.userId, oldEmail, newEmail, result)
.pipe(
    flatMap(userInfo => this.http.put(`http://localhost:3000/api/user/`, id))
);
```

Then catch the error when you can `updateUserEmail`:

```
this.updateUserEmail(id, oldEmail, newEmail, result).subscribe(
  result => console.log('worked'),
  error => console.log(error)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> You could put it just before the PUT request:

```
  .pipe(

    flatMap(userInfo =>
     if(userInfo) {

             this.http.put(`http://localhost:3000/api/user/`, id))
     }
  );
```